# create function for multiple addClass for use with enquire.js

Tags: jquery, function, addclass, enquire.js

I'm using [enquire.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/) in my current project. I'm using it to add css classes to several elements for large screens and remove those classes on smaller screens:

```
enquire.register("screen and (min-width: 48.0625em)", {
    match : function() {
        // absolute position for "bubble" lists
        $('.bubbles').addClass('structure');
        $('.structure li:nth-child(1)').addClass('s1');
        $('.structure li:nth-child(2)').addClass('s2');
        $('.structure li:nth-child(3)').addClass('s3');
        $('.structure li:nth-child(4)').addClass('s4');
        $('.structure li:nth-child(5)').addClass('s5');
        $('.structure li:nth-child(6)').addClass('s6');
        $('.structure li:nth-child(7)').addClass('s7');
        $('.structure li:nth-child(8)').addClass('s8');
        $('.structure li:nth-child(9)').addClass('s9');
    },

     unmatch : function () {
        $('.bubbles').removeClass('structure');
        $('.structure li:nth-child(1)').removeClass('s1');
        $('.structure li:nth-child(2)').removeClass('s2');
        $('.structure li:nth-child(3)').removeClass('s3');
        $('.structure li:nth-child(4)').removeClass('s4');
        $('.structure li:nth-child(5)').removeClass('s5');
        $('.structure li:nth-child(6)').removeClass('s6');
        $('.structure li:nth-child(7)').removeClass('s7');
        $('.structure li:nth-child(8)').removeClass('s8');
        $('.structure li:nth-child(9)').removeClass('s9');
    }
});
```

There's got to be a shorthand to this. I would have thought I could create a function something like:

```
$(.'bubbles').each(function() {
   // add all the classes here
}
```

Which would then be reversable in the `unmatch` function of enquire. Is this possible...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the index property of the `each` callback to toggle your classes:

```
enquire.register("screen and (min-width: 48.0625em)", {
    match: function () {
        // absolute position for "bubble" lists
        $('.bubbles').addClass('structure');
        $('.structure li').each(function (index) {
            $(this).toggleClass('s' + (index + 1));
        });
    },

    unmatch: function () {
        $('.structure li').each(function (index) {
            $(this).toggleClass('s' + (index + 1));
        });
        $('.bubbles').removeClass('structure');
    }
});
```